# Collections.sort() for date not working

Tags: java

I am trying to sort ArrayList w.r.t termDate.
ArrayList contains firstName,lastName,email,startDate,termDate,Status

Dates can be either empty or null. I have to compare accordingly and put all the null/empty date values at the end.

```
Collections.sort(usersList, new Comparator<User>() {
                public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
                    System.out.println("Term Date: " + o1.getTermDate() +" " +o2.getTermDate());
                    if((o1.getTermDate() == null || "".equals(o1.getTermDate())) && (o2.getTermDate() == null || "".equals(o2.getTermDate()))) {
                        System.out.println("Term Date1: 0 " + o1.getTermDate() + " " + o2.getTermDate());
                        return 0; //They are both null, both equal
                    }
                    if((o1.getTermDate() == null || "".equals(o1.getTermDate())) && (o2.getTermDate() != null || "".equals(o2.getTermDate()))) {
                        System.out.println("Term Date2: -1 " + o1.getTermDate() + " " + o2.getTermDate());
                        return -1; // The first is null and the second is not, return the first as lower than the second
                    }
                    if((o1.getTermDate() != null || "".equals(o1.getTermDate())) && (o2.getTermDate() == null || "".equals(o2.getTermDate()))) {
                        System.out.println("Term Date3: 1 " + o1.getTermDate() + " " + o2.getTermDate());
                        return 1; //The first is not null and the second is, return the first as higher than the second
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Term Date4: " + o1.getTermDate() + " " + o2.getTermDate());
                        return o1.getTermDate().compareTo(o2.getTermDate()); //Return the actual comparison
                    }
                }
            });
```

partial sysouts:

```
Term Date: null 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0
Term Date2: -1 null 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0
Term Date: null null
Term Date1: 0 null null
Term Date: 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date3: 1 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date: 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date3: 1 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date: 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date3: 1 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date: 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date3: 1 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date: 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0
Term Date4: 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0
```

partial output:

```
user,five,user5@gmail.com,08/07/2015,,Active
usernew2,two,usernew2@gmail.com,08/11/2015,,Active
myname2,hello3,qwerty1@gmail.com,08/11/2015,,Active
user,noUserAuth,user_nouserauth@gmail.com,08/21/2015,,Active
```

Comment: Are you sure your conditions are correct (because the inverted ones don't seem so :)? I would put them in two `boolean` variables and use and negate them in the `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code I assume your dates are **String** objects (as you compare them to empty Strings), and when I look at the output, the dates are **sorted alphabetically**, which is the expected output on this assumption.

Solution: change your model and use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) (on Java 8) or `Date` (pre Java 8) as data type.
Alternatively (not recommended), you can convert the Strings to `LocalDate` upon comparison (which inherently is slower).

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of TermDate ?
If it is a String, parse it to a date. (You should never have a string representation of a date if you have work to do on this date)
To compare two dates, define your comportment in case one is null, 
for the general case, return date1.compareTo(date2)